# php foreach submit button

Tags: php, foreach, submit

The issue I am having is that my form submit button, because it is within the foreach loop, ends up submitting for every single item that the foreach runs through.  If I put it on the outside of the loop the submit does not have the correct number to submit, it ends up submitting the last value in the foreach.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
    <div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true' data-icon='arrow-l'>
        <h3><?=$ticket['ticket_no']?> - <?=$ticket['title']?></h3>

        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a"> 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="c">
            <li data-role="list-divider"><h1></h1></li> 
            <li><h3>Description</h3><br><br><?=$ticket['description'] ?></li>
            <input type=hidden name=ticket_number value=<?= $ticket['ticket_no'];  ?>>
            <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="status" class="select">Change Status:</label>
                    <select name="status" id="<?=$ticket['ticket_no']?>">
                        <option value="Open">Status</option>
                        <option value="Tracker">Tracker</option>
                        <option value="Abandon">Abandon</option>
                        <option value="Communicate">Communicate</option>
                        <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </fieldset>
        </form>


        </div><!-- /themed container --> 
    </div> <!-- End inner collapsible set -->
```

}
?>

Comment: Cool coding style, the self-submitting form code ;) - the general answer is that you need to separate output and input processing from each other, see [IPO Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_Model).

Comment: so what u need exactly ?

Comment: why you are using html over here in loop? write it outside and then submit it with the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each form, put something like:

```
<input type=hidden name=ticket_number value=<?= $ticket['ticket_no'];  ?>>
```

and then move your if() to outside of the loop, and check for $_POST['ticket_number']

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['ticket_number'])) {
 $tickNum = $_POST['ticket_number'];
 updateTT($tickNum);                            
}
```

This was done with the least amount of change possible. Please sanitize your input, and all that good stuff!

Comment: This is assuming you want a Submit button for each ticket, and this isnt a single large form. If this is 1 large form, this is the wrong approach. If you want to list all your tickets on one page, but need to preform actions on each one individually, then use this method...

Comment: This is on the right track, but the form submit still does not correctly match with the ticket number.   Itends up still submitting the very last foreach item.

Comment: I had to change the code, I was using $_POST['status'] to get the ticket number, but this is set as the ID, and not the VALUE. Try the above code instead, adding the hidden form element. This should work, otherwise post resived code.

Comment: Snagged the issue, i put the hidden input outside of the form.  It is now corrected.  Thank you David.

Answer (score 0):

move the `<form>` tags from the loop as well as the button, that should work for you

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are currently overwriting your fields as they have same name.

[] is what you need !.

```
<select name="status[]" id="<?=$ticket['ticket_no']?>">
                            <option value="Open">Status</option>
                            <option value="Tracker">Tracker</option>
                            <option value="Abandon">Abandon</option>
                            <option value="Communicate">Communicate</option>
                            <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
</select>
```

now after you post u will get all tickets in status array. when u receive status loop it to get each value.

example of array post : http://www.pickndrive.info/questions.php

check the form html for example

Comment: This is assuming he wants to submit everything on the page. It appears to me that he wants a submit button for each ticket.

Comment: @David thank u for highlighting . he said "it ends up submitting the last value in the foreach" so i figured he need to submit all of them.
well if he need to submit everything that code, else then his code shall works fine !